# how to covert PST to IST Using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i get PST date formate from Database and i need to convert IST formate. But my system also in IST Formate. please check this http://jsfiddle.net/sfcdD/9/.

```
 var date = "2012-12-12 05:18:28.541"; // PST date formate fetch from db
 var offset = (3600000*(+5.30)); // IST gmtOffset value

 var dateformate = 'dd/mm/yyyy "at" h:MM TT';

 var dateArray = (date).split(' ');
 var year = dateArray[0].split('-');
 var time = dateArray[1].split(':');

 var  d = new Date($.trim(year[0]), $.trim(year[1]-1), $.trim(year[2]), $.trim(time[0]), $.trim(time[1]));

 utc = d.getTime() +(d.getTimezoneOffset()*60000); //d.getTimezoneOffset() is taking local timezone

 nd = new Date(utc + parseInt(offset));

 alert(dateFormat(nd,dateformate));  // dispaly 12/12/2012 at 5:06 AM but need to display 12/12/2012 at 7:48 PM
```

so my conversion is not work. it display wrong date.

Comment: You will need to convert the string to numbers before passing them into `new Date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var date = "2012-12-12 05:18:28.541";
var offset = (3600000*(+5.50+8));
var dateformate = 'dd/mm/yyyy "at" h:MM TT';

var dateArray = (date).split(' ');
var year = dateArray[0].split('-');
var time = dateArray[1].split(':');

var d = new Date($.trim(year[0]), $.trim(year[1]-1), $.trim(year[2]), $.trim(time[0]), $.trim(time[1]));
var nd = new Date(d.getTime() + offset);
alert(dateFormat(nd,dateformate));
```

Comment: A good solution, but I'm disappointed that JS does not have any native way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var offset = (3600000*(+5.30)); // IST gmtOffset value
```

should be

```
var offset = (3600000*(+5.50)); // IST gmtOffset value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but this not working. your system time is in IST formate?

Comment: No, I'm not in IST. What date/time does it return now?

Comment: I don't understand why you have made this so complicated. If all you want to do is convert a date/time from PST to IST, and the offset is constant, why not just hardcode that offset? Why convert to UTC first?